# How can I execute multiple commands in cmd in different lines of code in Python?

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess, python-os

I am trying to run multiple commands in command prompt using Python, but I want to organize them into separete lines of code, so it's easier for me to read and edit later.

I started by using:

```
import os

os.system('cmd /c "command_1 & command_2 & command_3 & ... & command_n"')
```

But as I developed my program, I began to need more and more commands and it became annoying very quickly. So I tried a lot of different formats and even tried using the `subprocess` module, but to no avail, since I can't seem to be able to separate the commands.

## Here are some examples that I tried, but *FAILED*:

*- Separating them into different functions:*

```
import os

os.system('cmd /k "command_1"')
os.system('cmd /k "command_2"')
...
os.system('cmd /c "command_n"')
```

This only executes the first command.

---

*- Separating them into different lines:*

```
import os

os.system(
'''
cmd /k "command_1 &
command_2 &
...
command_n"
'''
)
# I tried different variations of this, but none of them worked
```

These also execute only the first command, even when I try to put the "&" on the line below, or even with different formating. I tried passing each command as an argument, but this function can only get one.

Comment: only the first one runs because you used /k instead of /c

Comment: Wait, but doesn't /c closes the cmd?

Comment: yes and /k leaves it open so it is waiting for the user to type in a command instead of returning...

Comment: But I need these commands to be on the same command prompt, because they need to be executed in an specific directory

Edit: I see what you mean now that I tested. Thank you so much!

Comment: Don't use `os.system`. Use the `subprocess` module.

Comment: you can use os.chdir to change directory for python

Comment: @chepner Why shouldn't I use it?

Comment: You can provide a command and its arguments as separate strings, instead of going through the trouble of building a single string (with all the hassle of quoting that might entail) just for the shell to immediately parse that string back into the individual strings you started with. It also lets commands run in the background so your script can do other things while waiting for those commands to complete.

Comment: @Farlitz You can use pipe "|" to chain multiple commands.  eg.  `os.system('cmd /k mkdir folder1| cmd /k mkdir folder2')` to create 2 folders using 2 different commands . See at my code for reference. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74478101/17731030

Comment: @chepner I see. This program is just for setup, so it's only job is to execute some commands (installing pip and some libraries) so my other programs work on other computers, just so I don't need to do it manually every time. But thanks for the advice, I'll keep that in mind and I'm going to use subprocess instead of os.system.

Comment: @chepner Actually it's the opposite on Windows: `os.system` passes the single string, while `subprocess` requires you to split up the string into separate strings only for `subprocess` to put them back together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make up the single string on multiple lines:

```
os.system('cmd /c "'
   + 'command_1 & '
   + 'command_2 & '
   + 'command_3 & '
   ...
   + 'command_n"'
)
```

It's the same string, but formatted differently. Whereas the `'''` multi-line string includes the line-breaks in the string, this one doesn't.

Or you could write a multi-line string and remove the line breaks:

```
os.system(
'''
cmd /k "command_1 &
command_2 &
...
command_n"
'''.replace('\n', '')
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured that was the problem with the multi-line string, but I decided to keep it in my attempts just to better demonstrate what I tried already and see if someone could show me a way to work around it, but I didn't even consider doing those. In my case, the multi-line string should be best, because I need to use formated string.